# Azure Search Content Pack for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-cognitive-search

I'm looking to get some information about how well an azure search index is performing. I've enabled traffic manager and have downloaded the power BI report, but there doesn't appear to be any information about the index service itself? I've seen that there is a content pack for Azure search, but when I click 'Get Data', Azure search isn't an option. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you click **Get Data** in PowerBI, you should see a box labeled **Services** with a **Get** button.  Click this button and you'll find Azure Search in the list of services.  In the Azure portal, you'll also need to also enable "Archive to a storage account" on the Monitoring tab for your Azure Search service.  This storage account will be the actual source for the Data Set used by the Azure Search PowerBI dashboard.

For more information, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-azure-search

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. So I have to configure application insights as per this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-traffic-analytics as well as archive to storage under the diagnostics section?

Comment: Also, I can't see Services with a Get button in power BI desktop? Only via the browser?

Comment: Ah.  We're talking about 2 different things.  You are referring to traffic analytics, which requires you to log telemetry entries in your application code.  This is incredibly flexible, but requires extra work on your part.  Or, you can use the PowerBI Content Pack to see the information the service collects for you.  From your original question, it sounded more like you were looking for the content pack.  See the link above for more information.  Let me know what specific metrics you are looking for if this doesn't help.